# How to use histadd() with a custom function

Tags: functions, command-history

I've got the following in my `vim` config:

```
map <leader>ot :call OT()<cr>

function! OT()
    let fname = input("ot: ", "", "file")
    let res = system("ot --editor vim --print " . shellescape(fname))
    if v:shell_error
        echo "\n" . res
    else
        execute "e " res
    endif
endfunction
```

`<leader>ot` allows me to provide some data, like `Module::Name`, which then gets translated into an actual file name via [Open::This](https://metacpan.org/dist/Open-This/view/script/ot) and opened via the `execute` line. What I'd like to be able to do is to have an entry appear in my history (via `histadd()`?) which would allow me to re-run the function with the arguments I had originally supplied.

I've tried various incantations of `histadd` but I haven't been able to get there. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's change the `OT` function to take an argument so that it is not "stateful" (*i.e.*, a single history entry can correctly capture all the needed information):

```
nnoremap <leader>ot :call OT(input("ot: ", "", "file"))<cr>

function! OT(fname)
    let res = system("ot --editor vim --print " . shellescape(a:fname))
    if v:shell_error
        echo "\n" . res
    else
        execute "e " res
    endif
    call histadd(':', printf('call OT("%s")', escape(a:fname, '"\')))
endfunction
```

Then we can add the `histadd`, but we need to manipulate the string a bit to get it just right.

---

Alternately, just `:call histadd('@', fname)`, then run your mapping and press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>.

---

*N.B.* I used `nnoremap` instead of `map`.